# swift - How to make this layout using UICollectionView? (image attached)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, layout, uicollectionview

I should design UICollectionView like photo library of Facebook.

[image]

If I set `sizeForItemAt` to the right size, I thought it would be resolved automatically.

But it wasn't. This is my result.

[image]

I want cells stack from top to bottom densely.

How to fill the cell instead of the huge white space?

Comment: I think you can't using collection cell, instead use the First image as Collection views 's HeaderView

Comment: I think you have to make your own layout for your collection view. Have a look at this tutorial for instance: https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2

Comment: You need to implement custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout for that.